# Add column with product numbering on WooCommerce cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I'm trying to add numbers to each row in WooCommerce cart page, but i'm unable to get it working or even showing up.

My current code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'quadlayers_woocommerce_hooks');
function quadlayers_woocommerce_hooks() {
global $woocommerce;
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 0; $x++)
{
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

   //$product = $cart_item['data'];
   $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
   
}
}
    echo $x;
}
```

It should be something like this:

[image]

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adjustments you want are not possible via hooks, for this you will have to overwrite the [/cart/cart.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php) file.

- This template can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php.`
- These adjustments are provided for the template file with version number `@version 3.8.0`
- CSS adjustments may be required depending on the theme you are using

---

Replace line 28 - 29

```html
<th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
<th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
```

With

```html
<th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
<th class="product-number">&nbsp;</th>
<th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
```

---

Replace line 39 - 40

```php
<?php
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
```

With

```php
<?php
// Counter
$i = 1;
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
```

---

Replace line 65

```html
<td class="product-thumbnail">
```

With

```html
<td class="product-number">
    <?php
    echo $i;
    $i++;
    ?>
</td>

<td class="product-thumbnail">
```

---

Result:

[image]